# Can images be stored within SO account?

Tags: support, editor, images

Can I store images in my SO account that I otherwise link to (in a question)?

Comment: You can put links to already uploaded images in your profile's *About me*.

Comment: If you want to insert images in a post, just use imgur which is already supported.

Comment: Look here for a tutorial https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1228/will?tab=profile the "does this make you nervous" image in action: [Does this make you nervous?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgqut.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stack Exchange itself doesn't offer any storage mechanism of images or media, but you can use your personal profile (which is relatively full-fledged) to upload images to Stack Exchange's Imgur instance.

[image]

Do note that images in your profile are still subject to the same rules as images anywhere else, and may be removed by moderators at any time.